# Stationarity in LSTM multivariate prediction

Tags: time-series, prediction, stationarity, lstm

I am constructing a multivariate LSTM NN to predict a financial time series that is non-stationary at 1% significance level from an ADF test. However, the test rejects H0 of non-stationarity at 5%.

1. Is stationarity at 5% significance level satisfactory to make a time series prediction model?
2. If some of the predictors are non-stationary, would I have to e.g. difference both the predictors and the response variable, or could I just difference the predictors?
3. Would it be sound to transform the response variable with a 5 step difference (y = y(t+5)-y(t)) if I wanted to perform 5 steps ahead predictions, while only differencing the predictors with 1 step?